# How to hide everything after .cgi? in the address bar

Tags: python, cgi

I have a html file with a form:

```
<form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="bin/a_python_script.cgi">
```

(I 'have to' use method="get", because when I use method="post" I get weird 'Page expired' problems with the 'back' button in Internet Explorer 8)

The resulting page shows this in the address bar:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/bin/a_python_script.cgi?var1=a+variable&var2=another+variable&Submit=submit+this
```

My preferred output in the address bar would be:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/bin/a_python_script.html
```

How do I hide everything after ".cgi?" ?

And can I change ".cgi" into ".html" ?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there are no options other than changing the form method from 'get' to 'post'.

GET encodes all of the form fields into the URL. There's no way to hide anything without removing the data.

A quick Google search for "prevent page expired message" turns up quite a few results (the examples are mostly PHP, but the concept could be transferred to any language):

[Google - prevent page expired message](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=prevent%20page%20expired%20message)

Comment: Thank you Justin. I am not lucky with googling 'prevent page expired message'. did you find a result that I can use from my python cgi script?

Answer (score 2):

Your form method must be "post" and not "get".

In your cgi script, you should be able to retreive post data.

for the extension change, with a .htaccess it should works.

Comment: Thank you Pier-Alexandre. I tried several .htaccess 'voodoo' but that did not work. If extension change must be possible with .htaccess, then why not removing part(s) of the URL?

Comment: htaccess:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\a_python_script.html$ /bin/a_python_script.cgi [L]

Comment: I did not try the code I gave you, but there is a lot of tool for generating htaccess rewrite. Take a look onto: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Answer (score 1):

Leave the form as a POST, then use the [post-redirect-get](/questions/tagged/post-redirect-get) pattern to allow the user to go back or refresh without a warning.

Comment: Thank you Josh. I found the PRG wiki entry, and google did also turn up some results, but nothing that I can use with my python cgi script. This is part of my code: `try:
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
    my_html()' What should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Justin Niessner - however, after the hit you could do redirect to another page, so that the parameters will not remain in the URL. Or, you could submit the form via ajax in the background, so the user won't notice the params sent

Comment: Thank you Tudor. How exactly do I redirect to another page?